# Round Robin cpuscheduling in python - is it correct?

Tags: python, round-robin

I wrote a python code for the Round Robin algorithm, but the Gantt Chart provided as an answer on the Geeksforgeek site is different from the Gantt Chart provided by the code I created. What's wrong with my code?

```
def round_robin(processes, burst_time, arrival_time, time_quantum):
    n = len(processes)
    
    # Waiting times
    waiting_time = [0] * n
    # remaining burst time
    rem_burst = list(burst_time)
    # remaining arrival time
    rem_arrival = list(arrival_time)
    # Gantt chart
    gantt_chart = []
    
    t = 0
    while True:
        done = True
        for i in range(n):
            if rem_arrival[i] <= t and rem_burst[i] > 0:
                done = False
                if rem_burst[i] > time_quantum:
                    t += time_quantum
                    rem_burst[i] -= time_quantum
                    rem_arrival[i] = t
                    gantt_chart.append((processes[i], t))
                else:
                    t += rem_burst[i]
                    waiting_time[i] = t - burst_time[i] - arrival_time[i]
                    rem_burst[i] = 0
                    rem_arrival[i] = t
                    gantt_chart.append((processes[i], t))
        if done:
            break
    
    # Calculate Turnaround Time
    turnaround_time = [waiting_time[i] + burst_time[i] for i in range(n)]
    
    return gantt_chart, waiting_time, turnaround_time
```

- [right answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMqzr.jpg)
- [my code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZCHp.png)
- [geeksforgeek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYHUt.png)

Comment: Without seeing the data, we can't say very much.  There's something odd with P4.

Comment: @TimRoberts you mean you can't see the data that i uploaded? What's wrong with P4? Please tell me something more about that.

Comment: If you want to know if it's correct, write some unit tests

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that the third image included the sample data.  You should have posted it as text, but I do now see it.

Comment: When we get to T=6, P1 has been waiting for 4 time units, but P4 has only been waiting for 2.  Is that part of the spec?  Are you supposed to choose the "ready to run process than has been waiting the longest"?  Your code doesn't do that.